# How to execute handler in a different thread of the Main UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler, android-thread

I have in my activity a Handler which does two things, for `GAME_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_UI` message, must do some calculations outside the main thread, and for `GAME_ACTIVITY_REFRESH_UI` must execute itself in the main thread. I have a separated thread outside my activity, which must call that handler for the two things, and in one case must respect that its outside the main thread, but for the other case must respect that must execute the code in the main thread.

The problem is that when my outside tread calls the handler of the activity, the code of the handleMessage is **always** executed in the main thread. How can I maintain the thread that has called handler sendEmptyMessage for the case of `GAME_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_UI` instead of executing the code in the main ui thread?

My activity handler:

```
Handler gameHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case GAME_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_UI:
                updateUI();
                break;
            case GAME_ACTIVITY_REFRESH_UI:
                refreshUI();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

My outside thread which calls the handler

```
public void run() {
    while(true){
        //a lot more stuff
        gameHandler.sendEmptyMessage(GameActivity.GAME_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_UI);                    
        gameHandler.sendEmptyMessage(GameActivity.GAME_ACTIVITY_REFRESH_UI);
        //a lot more stuff
    }
}
```

Remember that:

**GAME_ACTIVITY_UPDATE_UI**: must execute in the separate thread (not working)
**GAME_ACTIVITY_REFRESH_UI**: must execute in the main thread (currently working)

Comment: have you used `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` and using this `handler` for calling `post` method?

Comment: @OmidZiyaee I posted the code i used, and take in mind that in one case i need to execute in main thread and in other in the other thread

Comment: So do you want to execute block code of `updateUI` method in a background thread inside MainActivity or in the outside thread (which calls sendEmptyMessage to UI-Thread of MainActivity)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? If your background task runs only for a few seconds then you should use this concept.

but if you are reluctant to change your code, I think you can do it like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBackListener {
View uiView;
private Handler gameHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:
                updateUiInBackground(MainActivity.this);
                break;
            case 1:
                refreshUiInUiThread();
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void updateUiInBackground(CallBackListener callBackListener) {
    //do some task in background
    //can not change uiView here
    callBackListener.backgroundWorkFinished();
}

private void refreshUiInUiThread() {
    //Do some task
    uiView.someMetheode();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uiView = findViewById(R.id.ui);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gameHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gameHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void backgroundWorkFinished() {
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            uiView.someMethod();
        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is the callback Class

```
 public interface CallBackListener {
      void backgroundWorkFinished();
 }
```